# Why does only the table head display?

Tags: php, pdo

The following code works perfectly well unless there is only one result, in which case only the `<tr>` containing the column names displays in the web page. Further, a search for the name 'Bracker' produces the result as described above but a search for 'Bra' works correctly while 'Brac' does not. The same does not apply to the name 'Dawe' which, if there is only one result,  only appears amongst many others when a search for 'Da' is undertaken.

```php
<?php
include  'connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit-keyword'])) {
    $keyword = ($_POST['keyword']);

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM Ely_NBR WHERE Founder LIKE ? ORDER BY DATE";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($qry);
    $stmt->execute(["%$keyword%"]);
    print "<table>";
    $result = ($stmt);
    //return only the first row (we only need field names)
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print " <tr>";
    foreach ($row as $field => $value){
        print " <th>$field</th>";
    } // end foreach
    print " </tr>";
    //second query gets the data
    $data = ($stmt);
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($data as $row){
        print " <tr>";
        foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
            print " <td>$value</td>";
        } // end field loop
        print " </tr>";
    } // end record loop
    print "</table>";

}
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using your first result row to display the column headings. When you call `PDOStatement::fetch()` it moves its internal cursor on the result set.
Therefore your loop to display the data starts printing the results from the 2nd row.

> See [PDOStatement::fetch() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php): Fetches the **next** row from a result set.

If you want to get the column names you may want to look at:

- [`PDOStatement::columnCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php)
- [`PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)

And print headings like this:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < $stmt->columnCount(); $i++) {
    $columnInfos = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
    echo '<th>' . $columnInfos['name'] . '</th>';
}
```

Comment: Used your 'for' code as above but now getting the error: 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::getColumnCount()'

Comment: @DennisGreenwood sorry I mistyped the method name. As I wrote in my answer, the method is `columnCount()` and not `getColumnCount()`. I fixed my code.

Comment: Many thanks AymDev. Problem solved. I understood the logic of your answer but am not a professional developer and not over familiar with how to develop the actual code, so this has been a great help.